Could Maedhros and Maglor have returned the Silmarils?
At the end of the War of Wrath, Maedhros and Maglor stole into the Eönwë's camp and stole the Silmarils. They were caught, but Eönwë allowed them to leave. Afterwards Maedhros committed suicide while Maglor hurled his Silmaril into the sea and wandered for eternity.
Given that the Oath of Fëanor only says they must fight:

whoso hideth or hoardeth, or in hand taketh, finding keepeth or afar casteth a Silmaril

and that Eönwë was clearly not keeping the Silmarils from them, it seems like their oath is complete. Could Maedhros and Maglor therefore have said "thank you very much", returned the Silmarils to Eönwë and/or taken them to Aman themselves, let Yavanna remake the Two Trees, and lived happily ever after? If the third Silmaril was a concern, they could even ask the Valar to temporarily take the star down, then return it.

The Oath doesn't have an end condition.  As soon as they give a Silmaril to someone else they then need to taketh it back.

@DavidW does it? From my reading of the oath, it only says they need to fight anyone who withholds the Silmaril from them. It doesn't say they can't give up the Silmaril after reacquiring it.

@Allure - "hideth OR hoardeth OR in hand taketh". Even taking in hand is enough to evoke the oath, not just withholding it.

@ibid I interpreted that as actual taking - that is, if I take something from you. It still doesn't preclude me giving you something.

No.
Here is the Oath

"Be he foe or friend, be he foul or clean, brood of Morgoth or bright
Vala, Elda or Maia or Aftercomer, Man yet unborn upon Middle-earth,
neither law, nor love, nor league of swords, dread nor danger, not
Doom itself, shall defend him from Fëanor, and Fëanor's kin, whoso
hideth or hoardeth, or in hand taketh, finding keepeth or afar casteth
a Silmaril. This swear we all: death we will deal him ere Day's
ending, woe unto world's end! Our word hear thou, Eru Allfather! To
the everlasting Darkness doom us if our deed faileth. On the holy
mountain hear in witness and our vow remember, Manwë and Varda!"

and here is the Doom of Mandos

"Tears unnumbered ye shall shed; and the Valar will fence Valinor
against you, and shut you out, so that not even the echo of your
lamentation shall pass over the mountains. On the House of Fëanor the
wrath of the Valar lieth from the West unto the uttermost East, and
upon all that will follow them it shall be laid also. Their Oath shall
drive them, and yet betray them, and ever snatch away the very
treasures that they have sworn to pursue. To evil end shall all things
turn that they begin well; and by treason of kin unto kin, and the
fear of treason, shall this come to pass. The Dispossessed shall they
be for ever. Ye have spilled the blood of your kindred unrighteously
and have stained the land of Aman. For blood ye shall render blood,
and beyond Aman ye shall dwell in Death's shadow. For though Eru
appointed to you to die not in Eä, and no sickness may assail you, yet
slain ye may be, and slain ye shall be: by weapon and by torment and
by grief; and your houseless spirits shall come then to Mandos. There
long shall ye abide and yearn for your bodies, and find little pity
though all whom ye have slain should entreat for you. And those that
endure in Middle-earth and come not to Mandos shall grow weary of the
world as with a great burden, and shall wane, and become as shadows of
regret before the younger race that cometh after. The Valar have
spoken."

Having retrieved the Silmarils, they found that they were no longer the valid inheritors, due to the Doom of Mandos and their crimes during the Kinslayings. Mandos speaks his dooms on order of Manwe, the Elder King, who is the representative of Eru. Hence they no longer had valid possession to hand on to Eönwe (or anyone else). They were merely thieves.

I think that's the correct answer as far as the characters in the story go, but they are bound mostly by their own blindness. As long as they live, everyone can change their minds including Feanor and the Valar (and they all do at times on other matters). They are both bound here by their foolish words because they themselves chose to be -- neither could say "Well, maybe I was wrong. Sorry." The Sons of Feanor could have interpreted their oath differently, but choose not to, and had they done so, the Valar could have said, "Well, things have changed." But neither did and that doomed them.

@MarkOlson they wouldn't have to say "maybe I was wrong" would they? They'd only have to say "Father was wrong, he should've given you the Silmarils".

@Allure Probably. The key point is that both the Sons of Feanor and the Valar erred (which happens to us all) but continued to stick stubbornly to their error. (Another bit of pettifogging that could have ended it is for Maglor to have adopted Yavanna into the family...)

The dooms are more like predictions, not edicts.

It is never revealed whether the Oath of Fëanor has magical power to compel those who took it to seek the Silmarils forever.  At various times, the sons of Fëanor seem free to wait years, even centuries, to take decisive action to recover the Silmarils, but eventually feel they must make the attempt.  However, it is unclear whether there is actual a magical compulsion placed on them, or whether they are merely acting out of misguided loyalty to their father and their oath.  So we cannot say for certain whether, had their personalities have been different, the sons of Fëanor might have turned away from the War of the Jewels; nor can we know whether, having recovered to of the gems after the War of Wrath, Maedros and Maglor could have handed them over to anyone other than another member of Fëanor's immediate family.
However, as the Noldor return to Middle-earth, Mandos tells them then and there, in the Prophecy of the North, that the oath-takers will never have peace because of it.

Their Oath shall drive them, and yet betray them, and ever snatch away the very treasures that they have sworn to pursue.

Mandos and Manwë can foresee that it is simply not in the nature and character of the Noldor oath-takers ever to be satisfied to live without the Silmarils returned to the House of Fëanor.  Whether or not they could have behaved reasonably with respect to the Jewels, the sons of Fëanor simply never would.
As to returning the Silmarils to Aman, that would not have been sufficient to renew the Two Trees.  Even Aulë, a greater craftsman than Fëanor, did not know how to break open the Silmarils to retrieve the pure light of the Two Trees within.  Only Fëanor could reveal that secret, which he will be unwilling to do until after the final Battle of Battles.
